# Calculating the norm of $T(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots)$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, closed-graph

Let X be a Banach space and $f_i \in X^*, i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty|| f_i(x)|| < \infty, \forall x \in X.  \hspace{2cm}(I)
$$

Calculate the norm of $T: X \to l^1(\mathbb{N})$ defined as $T(x)= (f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots)$.

I managed to prove that $T$ is continuous via the Closed Graph Theorem, but I could not use this technique to find its norm.

---

My first guess was $\sum_{i=1}^\infty || f_i||$, but this is not necessarily finite, even with hypothesis, as I could take $X = l^1(\mathbb{N})$ and taking the $\{f_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ to be the projections in its coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see what answer you're expected to give here.  The norm of $T$ certainly isn't determined by just the norms of the $f_i$.  For instance, if you take $f_1=f_2=\dots=f_n$ and $f_i=0$ for $i>n$, then $\|T\|=n\|f_1\|$.  On the other hand, your example with $X=l^1(\mathbb{N})$ shows that it's possible to have $\|f_i\|=1$ for all $i$ but $\|T\|=1$.  By similar examples along these lines, it should be possible to show that $\|T\|$ can be any finite value between $\sup \|f_i\|$ and $\sum \|f_i\|$.

Comment: Thank you, this was actually an exercise I of my class, I shall discuss that with the professor.